# I need to retrieve the terms from the Sharepoint term store a set of terms using rest

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am using this blog to get this but the call gives me a 500 error. Attached Postman's blog and pictures
[Blog Link](https://medium.com/@ankitgirgas/querying-sharepoint-term-store-with-rest-api-and-im-not-joking-3e158dc31e08)

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhBEp.png)

[Body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He0NS.png)

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Rest API didn't support to operation with Term Store.

I have tested this not long ago,but it report same error with you.

You could get terms with jsom.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/180497/get-the-termset-with-javascript-and-nothing-return

Comment: I can only use rest or soap. Would you know how to do it?

Comment: There should be no way to achieve your requirement.You could create a custom wcf to return all terms.https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24194.sharepoint-2013-create-a-custom-wcf-rest-service-hosted-in-sharepoint-and-deployed-in-a-wsp.aspx

Comment: Or I have a bad idea,you could save all term in a list,then you could get all terms by rest.

Comment: Thanks, I will try custom wc. The list does not help me because I have a list with many terms.